# Could not load NIB in bundle in ios5 pagebased application

Tags: ios5

I m calling rootviewcontroller from another view using below code

`rootviewpage = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil]; 
 [self.view addSubview:rootviewpage.view];`

but the application terminate..pls check below error message .Tanks

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'RootViewController''
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a nib (a .xib file that is used for interfaces) that has the name RootViewController in your project..